Is it possible to implement a recursive POD wrapper in C++?
I have a class to wrap POD struct types, but I'm having trouble when a POD struct has another POD inside, because my wrapper class only stores the POD as it is, using composition.
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class POD {
protected:
    T pod_;

public:
    POD(T&& pod)
    : pod_{std::move(pod)}
    {
    }

    POD(const T& pod)
    : pod_{pod}
    {
    }

    const T& cpod() const { return pod_;}
};

extern "C" {
    typedef struct {
        float x;
        float y;
    } v2f_t;

    typedef struct {
        v2f_t start;
        v2f_t end;
        int foo;
        int bar;
    } line_t;
}

// example usage
class Vector2f: public POD<v2f_t> {
public:
    Vector2f(v2f_t&& pod) 
    : POD<v2f_t>(std::move(pod))
    {}

    Vector2f(const v2f_t& pod) 
    : POD<v2f_t>(pod)
    {}

    float sum() {
        return pod_.x + pod_.y;
    }
};

class Line: public POD<line_t> {
    Line(line_t&& pod) 
    : POD<line_t>(std::move(pod))
    {}

    float total_sum() {
        // I would like to call
        // start.sum() + end.sum();
        // but start and end are of type v2f_t so
        // I need to create some kind of temporal POD wrappers
        return Vector2f(pod_.start).sum() + Vector2f(pod_.end).sum();
    }

}

Is there some way to tell the compiler that one POD has another POD inside and change the POD wrapper class to have some kind of template parameter with the inner POD?
// something like
class Line: public POD<line_t, Vector2f> {
  // members would now be something similar to
  Vector2f start;
  Vector2f end;
  int foo;
  int bar;

}


Uhhh. Make Vector2f get_start() and same for end, and use them in your sum(). But I question the value of wrapping such simple types instead of writing them from scratch and providing functions to convert between the two.

And ask yourself why you need all this complexity to begin with. Is part of this somehow required to be compatible with C or...?

What's POD? Why do you need to specify explicit move and copy constructors?

I have no clue what POD is supposed to achieve and how any member names are to be decided.

A move constructor for a POD type specifically is pointless. It doesn't do anything different from the copy constructor. Similarly, it is pointless to declare the copy constructor, because the implicit one is always correct for a POD type. Is the goal here only to make the members private/protected in the inherited class? If so, you don't need the wrapper. You can specify private or protected on the base class specifier instead of public and use the original type directly.


I have a class to wrap POD struct types

Why?
Just use free functions with parameters of your C structs.
float sum(const v2f_t & vector) {
    return vector.x + vector.y;
}

float total_sum(const line_t & line) {
    return sum(line.start) + sum(line.end);
}


If you really think these classes are important, then POD<T> needs to be able to point to a T instead of having a T data member sometimes.
template <typename T>
class POD {
private:
    std::variant<T, T*> data;

    template <bool is_const>
    struct extractor {
        using pointer = std::conditional_t<is_const, const T*, T*>;
        using reference = std::conditional_t<is_const, const T&, T&>;
        reference operator()(pointer ptr) const { return *ptr; } 
        reference operator()(reference ref) const { return ref; } 
    }

public:
    POD(T pod)
    : data{std::in_place<T>, pod}
    {}

    POD(T* ptr)
    : data{std::in_place<T*>, ptr}
    {}

    T& get() { return std::visit(extractor<false>{}, data); }

    const T& get() const { return std::visit(extractor<true>{}, data); }
};

class Vector2f: public POD<v2f_t> {
public:
    using POD<v2f_t>::POD;

    float sum() {
        return get().x + get().y;
    }
};

class Line: public POD<line_t> {
private:
    Vector2f start;
    Vector2f end;

public:
    Line(line_t line) : POD<line_t>(line), start(&get().start), end(&get().end) {}

    Line(line_t * ptr) : POD<line_t>(ptr), start(&ptr->start), end(&ptr->end) {}

    float total_sum() {
        return start.sum() + end.sum();
    }    
};

